# Re-order html elements without removing them visually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Alright first things first.
What i'm trying to accomplish is to create my own "semi-3d" circular carousel.
There is many of them out there and some very nice ones like iCarousel (which is somewhat what i'm going for)

Thing is i wanted to make my own just for the hell of it and i figure it's good practice.

So far i have this http://jsfiddle.net/Puzzle/Pmxjf/10/

```
     $this.Shift = function (items, end) {
        if (end == true) {
            $this.children().each(function () {
                // Rearrange all items
                $this.CalculateNewPos(this);
                $this.Rotate(this);
            });
        }
        else {
            $this.children().each(function () {
                // Rearrange all items
                $this.CalculateNewPos(this);
                $this.Rotate(this);
            });
        }
    }

    $this.ShiftRight = function(items, index)
    {
        $(items[index]).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).insertAfter($this.children().last());
            $this.Shift(items, false);
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }

    $this.ShiftLeft = function(items, index, currentItem)
    {
        $(items[currentItem - index]).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).insertBefore($this.children().first());
            $this.Shift(items, true);
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }
```

this code basically does all the removal.
And the rotation code you can find in the jsfiddle.

As you can see the angling works well on the first load but upon rotating it somewhat fails.
And also the fading looks good but then  when you click the image divs on the end it fades 2 at a time.

And worst of all. the entire carousel shifts when i use insertBefore and insertAfter.

My braincracker right now is to figure out how i can make them move smoothly to the end or the beginning of the stack by pure animation.

Does any of you have a clue where i should start looking?
i looked through the iCarousel code and that's a crazy amount of raw math that i'm not ready to tackle yet.

Thanks :)

Comment: The problem you are going to have is that this problem is basically raw math. There is no getting around it.This problem is all about projecting a 3d image to a 2d plane essentially.

Comment: So you think the only way to do this is to rotate and translate the elements based solely on css3? GAH i was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Its essentially the only way to mimic a 3d effect in 2d. You are trying to achieve depth on a 2D plane. Impossible obviously, but you can trick the human eye pretty easily it turns out.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object none has no method 'setFromString'`

Comment: Hmm very well. This is going to be a fun one! Back to the drawingboard i guess :D. Thanks dude!

Comment: Jan that's an issue with the jquery.transit.js not my code i was using that as a shortcut but if i can't do it the way i want i might aswell write that code myself too. try a different browser seems to work for me in chrome but not in firefox for some reason

Comment: Your jsFiddle doesn't seem to do anything other than display five stacked coloured blocks. Have you posted the wrong link?